# dns server that would resolve any domain to 192.168.1.1

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm looking for a lightweight dns server that could resolve any possible domain name to a specific IP address (e.g 192.168.1.1).

```
. -> 192.168.1.1
com -> 192.168.1.1
org -> 192.168.1.1
google.com -> 192.168.1.1
yahoo.com  -> 192.168.1.1
....
anypossibledomainname.evenifitdoesntexist.blah -> 192.168.1.1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS? Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you realy want a DNS-Server, then check out [DNSMasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html). Using the `--address` Command-Line-Switch and the `#` wildcard, this should be very easy:

> The domain specification works in the
>   same was as for --server, with the
>   additional facility that /#/ matches
>   any domain. Thus --address=/#/1.2.3.4
>   will always return 1.2.3.4 for any
>   query not answered from /etc/hosts or
>   DHCP and not sent to an upstream
>   nameserver by a more specific --server
>   directive.

Also check out the `--no-hosts` commandline switch.

See the [Man-Page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html)

Comment: Great. Just what I've been looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You also need to make sure that dnsmasq doesn't query upstream servers by editing resolv.conf to wrap back to the local machine `nameserver 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 4):

You're not looking for a DNS server but for a Captive Portal solution, wich is in fact a proxy.

Comment: I really really do need a DNS server. The description of a "Captive Portal" is provided so that people could get an idea, why I would need a DNS server with such a weird setup. Sorry for being misleading.

Comment: I've only seen this with captive portals (proxies). They redirect when you don't have credentials to go to the site you want, it's not a DNS thing as much as a redirect to a EULA-type page where you get a chance to authenticate. I don't think you can do this thinking like a DNS server because the DNS server wouldn't know how to resolve everything on the Internet all at once; it's not what it's for.

Comment: Ok, I'd better remove the "captive portal" description from the question.

Comment: I think you might get non "captive portal" answers if you described why exactly you think you need a DNS server to do this.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is not a DNS server, but a proxy server. Something like this: http://www.hottproxy.org

Comment: proxy servers do not resolve names to IPs, do they?

Comment: @facha No they don't. But you don't want your customers to resolve names to IPs, you want them to be redirected to a specific Webpage. And DNS servers don't redirect to web server do they?

Comment: Sorry for being misleading, I really really do want customers to resolve names to IPs. This is what I'm looking for: "DNS server that would resolve any domain to 192.168.1.1"

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Cisco router, it can be setup to do this:

> ip dns server
>   ip dns spoofing 192.168.1.1